# Why can I not access this class member in python?

Tags: python, class-members

I have the following code

```
class Transcription(object):
    WORD = 0
    PHONE = 1
    STATE = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.transcriptions = []

    def align_transcription(self,model,target=Transcription.PHONE):
        pass
```

The important part here is that I would like to have a class member as default value for a variable. This however gives the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Transcription' is not defined
```

Why is this not possible and what is the right (pythonic) way to do something like this.

Comment: The right way? Hard to say, what are you trying to do? Why would you pass the class of an object to a function of that object? I don't see what you are trying to do here.

Comment: He wants to use a constant scoped to the class as a default value for a method parameter.

Comment: Right you are. My bad. The syntax coloring blinded me. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't access it because `Transcription` isn't defined at the time that the `def` statement is running.

```
 def align_transcription(self,model,target=PHONE):
        pass
```

will do the trick. The `PHONE` name is available in the namespace which will become the `Transcription` class *after* the `class` statement finishes executing.

The way this works is that `class` is a statement that *actually gets run*. When Python encounters a class statement, it enters a new local scope and executes everything that's indented under the `class` statement as if it were a function. It then passes the resulting namespace, the name of the class and a tuple of the baseclasses to the *metaclass* which is `type` by default. The metaclass returns an instance of itself which is the actual class. None of this has occurred when the `def` statement executes.

The statement

```
class Foo(object):
    a = 1
    def foo(self):
        print self.a
```

creates a namespace `ns = {'a': 1, 'foo': foo}` and then executes

```
Foo = type('Foo', (object,), ns)
```

This is equivalent to

```
def foo(self):
    print self.a

Foo = type('Foo', (object,), {'a': 1, 'foo': foo})
```

You can clearly see that `Foo` is not defined at the time that `foo` is being defined so `Foo.a` makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

The class is not associated with its name until the end of the definition.

The way I would write this (and I can't guarantee that it's Pythonic) is:

```
class Transcription(object):
    WORD = 1   # zero won't work below... need to change the value
    PHONE = 2
    STATE = 3

    def align_transcription(self, model, target=None):
        target = target or Transcription.PHONE
        # or
        if target is None: target = Transcription.PHONE
```

Alternatively, setting `PHONE` to zero instead of `WORD` will be fine. The `if` statement will work regardless of the values of the constants, but the `or` will replace a zero value with `PHONE`.

Other options are to define the constants in another class or to bind the `align_transcription` method outside of the class:

```
class Transcription(object):
    WORD = 0
    PHONE = 1
    STATE = 2

def _unbound_align_transcription(self, model, target=Transcription.PHONE):
    pass

Transcription.align_transcription = _unbound_align_transcription
```

Comment: Or do it as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655745/why-can-i-not-access-this-class-member-in-python/4655770#4655770 ... I knew that, just didn't think of it immediately.

Comment: I think a simple response like "The class object is not available until its definition is complete' is fine too.

Comment: Which is true, except values defined within the class `are` available. The trick is that bound function *signatures* (the `def` line) are in the class scope at the point of definition, while bound function *code* is not, and needs to use the class name to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

The Transaction class does not exist yet when you define the align_transcription method, but PHONE is available in the scope.
So, you can do either this way:

```
class Transcription(object):
    WORD = 0
    PHONE = 1
    STATE = 2

def __init__(self):
    self.transcriptions = []

def align_transcription(self,model,target=PHONE):
    pass
```

or with a target=None default if you plan to override PHONE in subclasses or instances:

```
def align_transcription(self,model,target=None):
    if target is None:
        target = self.PHONE
```